# Unable to resolve 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present' issue in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server database through Web API and show the result in browser using Angular. But, I keep on getting below error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7216/api/departments' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Below is the complete code in `Program.cs` file of API project. I copied complete code why because, sometimes relevance of placing `addCors()`, and `useCors()` also does matter.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Warning()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File("logs/Log_Of_Practice.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseSerilog();
// Add services to the container.

ApplicationServices(builder.Services, builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDepartmentRepository, DepartmentRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExampleService, ExampleService>();

builder.Services.AddCors();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .WithOrigins("https://localhost:7216/api/departments/")
);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

static void ApplicationServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    services.AddSwaggerGen();

    services.AddSingleton<EmployeeDataStore>();

    services.AddDbContext<CompanyContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(configuration["ConnectionStrings:PracticeDbConnectionString"]));
    services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
}
```

Below is the complete code in *app.component.ts* file

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Angular Learnings - Show All Departments';
  departments: any;
  successState = true;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:7216/api/departments').subscribe({
      next: response => {
        this.successState = true;
        this.departments = response;
      },
      error: error => {
        this.successState = false;
        console.log(error);
      },
      complete: () => {
        if(this.successState) {
          console.log('Request was processed successfully');
        }
        else if(!this.successState) {
          console.log('Request was unable to process successfully. See log for more details');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

My app.component.html is a simple mark-up. This file contains nothing except below code.

```
<div class="container">
  {{ departments }}
</div>
```

When I execute the above code, I keep on getting below error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7216/api/departments' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
app.component.ts:25 HttpErrorResponseerror: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:7216/api/departments: 0 Unknown Error"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 0statusText: "Unknown Error"url: "https://localhost:7216/api/departments"[[Prototype]]: HttpResponseBase
:7216/api/departments:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

When searched in Google, I found [this nice article](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/do-you-know-how-to-resolve-cors-issues-in-angular-9d818474825f) and followed the steps mentioned like here with no luck.

Can someone please let me know where I am doing wrong!

Comment: You should whitelist the Angular App in the ..NET Core Web API application.  `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")`, as currently you are adding the wrong URL for CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint to be whitelisted in the CORS is incorrect, currently, you are whitelisting the API action, by right you need to whitelist the Angular application.

```cs
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
);
```

**Bonus**

You should set the CORS endpoints in the *appsettings.json* rather than in the *Program.cs* for handling multiple environments such as Development, Staging, Production, etc. Reference: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&source=recommendations#application-configuration-providers)

> appsettings.{Environment}.json

```
{
  "CorsOrigins": "https://localhost:4200"
}
```

To get the configuration from the *appsettings.json*:

```cs
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .WithOrigins(builder.Configuration["CorsOrigins"])
);
```